# multiprocessing.Process doesn't work as I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, robots.txt

I wrote a program, and I want to run a function with multiprocessing.Process, but I get no result.

```py
import sys, urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request


def disallow(line):
    if "Disallow" in line:
        print(line.replace("Disallow: ", ""))


def parse_robot_txt(url):
    url += "robots.txt"
    req = Request(url, data=None,
        headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"},)
    robots = urlopen(req).read().decode("UTF-8")
    lines = str(robots).splitlines()

    for l in lines:
        multiprocessing.Process(target=disallow, args=(l,))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse_robot_txt("https://moz.com/")
```

Out:

I didn't get result,
but if I run without multiprocessing:

```py
import sys, urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request


def disallow(line):
    if "Disallow" in line:
        print(line.replace("Disallow: ", ""))


def parse_robot_txt(url):
    url += "robots.txt"
    req = Request(url, data=None,
        headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"},)
    robots = urlopen(req).read().decode("UTF-8")
    lines = str(robots).splitlines()

    for l in lines:
        disallow(l)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse_robot_txt("https://moz.com/")
```

Out:

```
/products/content/  
/local/enterprise/confirm  
/researchtools/ose/        
/page-strength/*  
/thumbs/*  
/api/user?*  
/checkout/freetrial/*  
/local/search/  
/local/details/  
/messages/  
/content/audit/*  
/content/search/*  
/marketplace/  
/cpresources/  
/vendor/  
/community/q/questions/*/view_counts  
/admin-preview/*
```

So, what's the problem of multiprocessing? How can I use it to get the same result?

Comment: This does not look like a problem where multiprocessing can improve speed. String replace is fast compared to urlopen. Have you profiled your code to identify the 'slow' parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the Process, simply change it to:

```
for l in lines:
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=disallow, args=(l,))
    proc.start()
```

Comment: I did it, and it worked, but it didn't speed up the process

Comment: First of all, if this answers your question, please mark it as accepted.
Second of all, that's surprising that's it's slower, can you share the runtime of both examples?

Comment: @PaliProx: Why would you expect adding more overhead to processing each line to speed things up?

Comment: @OfekGlick 
```python
for l in lines:
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=disallow, args=(l,))
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
```
and used time.time() to calculate the duration of process, returned 9.4, but when I used this, returned 0.4:
```python
for l in lines:
    disallow(l)
```

Comment: The reason it took longer it because you added `proc.join()`, it tells the parent process to wait untill the child is done. Remove it and you will see the increase in preformance

Comment: @OfekGlick But I need to use `proc.join()` because I want them in the order. Even if I remove that, the taken time wasn't lower than 4 secs

Comment: Then using Process does not seem logical here, as it is intended to run in parallel, and not sequential.

Comment: First of all, nothing about this code will guarantee *any* particular order in which the processes that are created will run and complete and therefore the order in which the print statements are executed even if it is *likely* that it will be in creation order. Second, due to the overhead in creating new processes and passing arguments from one address space to another, to reap the benefits of parallel processing your processes need to be doing more that what `disallow` is doing here and *that* is why this will run more slowly than just calling `disallow` in a loop with no multiprocessing.

Comment: To guarantee a specific order, you should create a process pool, for example a `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` instance, then call the `map` function passing `lines` as the argument. `disallow` should then be modified to just *return* the modified line. `map` will then return a list of modified lines, which can then be printed by the *main process*.